# R dataframe: sum of certain rows into new column

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a dataframe in which I'd like to create a new column where each cell is formed by the sum of some other rows.

My dataframe would be like:

```
    Type    A    B    C
1     X     1    6    5
2     X     3    4    0
3     Y     4    1    0
4     Z     0    0    1
```

And my expected output:

```
    Type    A    B    C    D
1     X     1    6    5    12
2     X     3    4    0    7
3     Y     4    1    0    5
4     Z     0    0    1    1
```

I need to add the names of the columns I want to sum as a vector, such as `c("A","B","C")`, and I've tried functions such as `rowSums` and `rowsum` but they're not working properly.

Comment: `df$D <- rowSums(df[c("A","B","C")])`

Comment: is there a way to add them inside a `mutate` function?

Comment: `df %>% mutate(D = rowSums(select(., A, B, C)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution with `dplyr`:

```r
df <- tribble(
~"A", ~"B", ~"C",
1, 6, 5,
3, 4, 0,
4, 1, 0,
0, 0, 1
)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(D = sum(c_across(A:C)))
```